# Unable to call Native method from .so file (Loading of library is success ) in Android studio With NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk

1. I had created the sample project(HellWorldJNI) that runs with Android Ndk and prints "Hello world from Jni" message from the native C.
2. And then i extract the HelloWorldJNI.apk file of the sample from the Output/apk directory of the project.
3. So i got the all the .so files from different devices(like arm64-v8a,armeabi,x86..etc)
4. Now i created a new project (CallJNIFromSoFile) and created jniLibs folder inside main folder , and copied the all .so files of HelloWorldJNI app into this new project.
5. After that i load the library and the function name of the HelloWorldJNI App like this

   ```
   static {
       System.loadLibrary("hello-android-jni");
   }

   public native  static String getMsgFromJni();
   ```
6. Here i got strucked, i am able load the "hello-android-jni" library without any problem. But the native method getMsgFromJni() from the above is showing in RED color and not able call that method.

   Not at all receiving the message "Hello world from Jni"

   This is my Logcat Output:

   ```
   java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for java.lang.String
   at com.example.hari.myopencvvsample.MainActivity.getMsgFromJni(Native Method)
   ```

Please suggest am i missing anything other than the above steps. I tried many ways like regenerating the .so files and then put it again,but didn't worked .  Sorry for my english.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I’m struggling with the exact same thing! May I know how you solve it in the end? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a JNI implementation of the method `getMsgFromJni()`. The .so files are shared libraries, which you can link to and use from C or C++ code, but you need to provide an interface for any C or C++ methods you plan to call from Java, hence **J**ava **N**ative **I**nterface.

If you look at the src/main/jni folder in your HelloWorldJNI project, you will see a C or C++ file which implements any native methods called from Java in that project. You can also refer to the [NDK samples](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk) for more help. The [hello-libs example](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/master/hello-libs) is a good place to start for your question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.    It already had the implementation of methord getMsgFromJni()  and worked fine when i run my project HelloWorldJNI.

Comment: It shows the message like  "Hello world from Jni"  which is there in my method implemetation.  But in my second project (CallJNIFromSoFile) where i copied only .so file of HelloWorldJNI project, and load the library and called the method   getMsgFromJni() like this                               static {
    System.loadLibrary("hello-android-jni");
}                                                                                                            public native  static String getMsgFromJni();                                          this is where it's not working.

Comment: Yes, because you only copied the .so files. You can create a dependency on the prebuilt libraries, but you will not be able to use them without providing JNI.

Comment: so how to create jni @Francesca Nannizzi

Answer (score 0):

This is completely **bad** idea to copy *so files between Android projects.
JNI will find your function by the name which depends from the name of your Android application java-class hierarchy.
Accordingly your description you compiled HelloWorldJni apk first and you have symbols there something like:

```
T Java_com_example_helloworldjni_MainActivity_getMsgFromJni
```

As you see there is your java-class hierarchy included in name of this function.
And then, you are creating your own application **with different class-names** and your program looks for something like:

```
Java_com_example_hari_myopencvvsample_MainActivity_getMsgFromJni
```

inside your library, but as you know - it is not there.
I'd suggest you to read the article https://developer.android.com/ndk/samples/sample_hellojni.html
with its part about c implementation carefully, and repeat all the steps for your new CallJNIFromSoFile project.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.                                                                            The scenario is like this . I have Project A  and A.SO which you have generated by building A. Now, i want have Project B and i want to use A.SO in Project B. Project B is is Simple Android Project instead of Native.

Answer (score 0):

Use targetSdkVersion less than 23 it will be working fine..

```
         defaultConfig {
             versionCode 1
             versionName "1.0.0"

             minSdkVersion 15
             targetSdkVersion 22
```